# How to make pages with "?page=" non-indexable in Shopify?

Tags: shopify

I want all pages that contain "?page=" to be     Noindex in     Shopify.

such as

```
https://vincudorshop.ro/collections/spumante?page=2
https://vincudorshop.ro/collections/gourmet?page=2
https://vincudorshop.ro/collections/vinuri?page=5
```

I tried to edit robots.txt file to make those URL disallowed and theme.liquid file, but it did not work for me.
Can somebody help me to resolve this problem?

Comment: please, consider adding more content to the question, like what have you tried so far, the expected input/output of the code and where's the unexpected behavior happening.

Answer (score 0):

The best way to do so if you have multiple pages like this:

1. From your Shopify admin, go to Online Store > Themes.
2. Find the theme you want to edit and click Actions > Edit code.
3. Locate the theme.liquid file (or possibly template.liquid, depending on the theme's structure).
4. Within the  section, add the following code:

```
{% if request.params.page %}
  <meta name="robots" content="noindex">
{% endif %}
```

Here it's checking for page parameter in url and if condition is true it will add the meta tag for robots

Comment: I tried but it does not work. They are still indexable

Comment: Maybe those pages are already indexed though google analytics and Google search console apply these code and login to your google search console and select your domain and there you will get an option to remove indexed url from Google and also add one more line within if condition  and one outside if condition.                      <meta name="revisit-after" content="7 days"> {% if request.params.page %}
  <meta name="robots" content="noindex">. <meta name="crawler" content="noindex">
{% endif %}

Comment: And add a robots.txt too to disallow all useragent with particular get request

Comment: @KumarSinha have you actually tried and tested this yourself? Because this code outputs absolutely nothing... 